# Insert vector {x, y, z} into another vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm looking for some pointers on inserting or pushing a vector into another vector.

The idea is I have vec1 = {1, 2, 3} for example.
Then I want to insert this into vec2 before next vec1 = {4, 5, 6} turns up.

The problem is I don't want vec 2 to read {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, I want it to read

vec2 = {1, 2, 3},
       {4, 5, 6},... etc

Is this possible or I'm I completely mad. Any help will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: a vector of vectors perhaps?

Comment: Are you looking for `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: You need `vector< vector<int> > vv; vv.push_back(vec1);` etc

Comment: If each vector has exactly 3, might want to make a vector of tuple instead

Comment: @RPGillespie That's a good point, but if the leaf elements are all the same, you can use `std::vector<std::array<int,3>>` rather than a vector of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vector of vector of integers. Like this :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvecs = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
```

You can also use this :

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vecofvecs;
    std::vector<int> subvec1 = { 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> subvec2 = { 4,5,6 };

    vecofvecs.push_back(subvec1);
    vecofvecs.push_back(subvec2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That copies the 'inner' vectors - feels like this might not be the intent.